How can I handle misaligned columns with BeautifulSoup?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("http://www.californiagasprices.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", class_="p_v2")

header = [th.get_text(strip=True) for th in table.tr.select("th")]

all_data = []
for row in table.select("tr:has(th)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("th")]
    tdx = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
    all_data.append(tds)
    all_data.append(tdx)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=header)
print(df)
#df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

I tried this code to scrap data from a website but my table output is not aligned correctly. I would expect the table to look like this:



Price
Station
Area
Thanks




3.85
Valero, 122 W Hermosa St & N Elmwood Ave
Lindsay
DAVEFMCC, 2 hours ago


3.85
Fastrip,
195 W Hermosa St & N Sweetbriar Ave
DAVEFMCC, 2 hours ago



But it looks like this instead:



Price
Station
Area
Thanks




Price
Station
Area
Thanks








3.8





Valero122 W Hermosa St & N Elmwood Ave

Lindsay
DAVEFMCC7 hours ago



How can I fix it?
FYI this is my sample HTML code from the table I want to extract from the website:
<table cellspacing="0" class="p_v2">
                <thead>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <th class="pr">
                            Price
                        </th>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            Station
                        </th>
                        <th style="width: 91px">
                            Area
                        </th>  
                        <th class="ts nb">
                            Thanks
                        </th>               
                    </tr>    
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_0" sm="0" ph="102144">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <div class="cash-icon" "=""> </div><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=102144" title="Update this price" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Price Confirmed',{'Context':'Price Report'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" class="p_price" id="p_102144"><div class="price_num" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:12px">3.85</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=102144" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/Valero_Gas_Stations/Lindsay/102144/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">Valero</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>122 W Hermosa St &amp; N Elmwood Ave</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=102144&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Lindsay/index.aspx" class="p_area">Lindsay</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=DAVEFMCC" class="mem">DAVEFMCC</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_redcar"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 2:03 PM"> 3 hours ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_1" sm="1" ph="102139">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <div class="cash-icon" "=""> </div><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=102139" title="Update this price" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Price Confirmed',{'Context':'Price Report'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" class="p_price" id="p_102139"><div class="price_num" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:12px">3.85</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=102139" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/Fastrip_Gas_Stations/Lindsay/102139/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">Fastrip</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>195 W Hermosa St &amp; N Sweetbriar Ave</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=102139&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Lindsay/index.aspx" class="p_area">Lindsay</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=DAVEFMCC" class="mem">DAVEFMCC</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_redcar"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 2:03 PM"> 3 hours ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_2" sm="2" ph="33713">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <div class="cash-icon" "=""> </div><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=33713" title="Update this price" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Price Confirmed',{'Context':'Price Report'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" class="p_price" id="p_33713"><div class="price_num" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:12px">3.93</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=33713" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/Fastrip_Gas_Stations/Gridley/33713/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">Fastrip</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>1687 CA-99 &amp; Spruce St</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=33713&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Gridley/index.aspx" class="p_area">Gridley</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=Owner" class="mem">Owner</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_browncar"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 1:10 PM"> 4 hours ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_3" sm="3" ph="105064">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=105064" title="Update this price" class="p_price" id="p_105064"><div class="price_num" style="margin-left:12px">3.95</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=105064" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/Fast_Stop_Mini_Mart_%232_Gas_Stations/Redding/105064/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">Fast Stop Mini Mart #2</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>3101 S Market St &amp; Grange St</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=105064&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Redding/index.aspx" class="p_area">Redding</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=Buddy_2e0rkhe9" class="mem">Buddy_2e0rkhe9</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_browncar"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 4:04 PM"> 1 hour ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_4" sm="4" ph="209780">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <div class="cash-icon" "=""> </div><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=209780" title="Update this price" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Price Confirmed',{'Context':'Price Report'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" class="p_price" id="p_209780"><div class="price_num" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:12px">3.95</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=209780" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/EZ_Trip_Gas_Stations/Fresno_-_NW/209780/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">EZ Trip</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>2171 W Shaw Ave &amp; N Crystal Ave</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=209780&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Fresno_-_NW/index.aspx" class="p_area">Fresno - NW</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=Johnny6496" class="mem">Johnny6496</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_redcar"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 11:22 AM"> 6 hours ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_5" sm="5" ph="11657">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <div class="cash-icon" "=""> </div><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=11657" title="Update this price" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Price Confirmed',{'Context':'Price Report'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" class="p_price" id="p_11657"><div class="price_num" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:12px">3.95</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=11657" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/EZ_Trip_Travel_Center_Gas_Stations/Fresno_-_NW/11657/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">EZ Trip Travel Center</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>6639 N Parkway Dr &amp; W Herndon Ave</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=11657&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Fresno_-_NW/index.aspx" class="p_area">Fresno - NW</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=goletagiant" class="mem">goletagiant</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_redcarspeed"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 9:18 AM"> 8 hours ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_6" sm="6" ph="362">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <div class="cash-icon" "=""> </div><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=362" title="Update this price" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Price Confirmed',{'Context':'Price Report'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" class="p_price" id="p_362"><div class="price_num" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:12px">3.99</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=362" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/Fuel_Club_Gas_Stations/Covina/362/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">Fuel Club</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>110 W Arrow Hwy &amp; N Citrus Ave</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=362&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Covina/index.aspx" class="p_area">Covina</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=wpruss" class="mem">wpruss</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_redcarspeed"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 2:04 PM"> 3 hours ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_7" sm="7" ph="35339">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=35339" title="Update this price" class="p_price" id="p_35339"><div class="price_num" style="margin-left:12px">3.99</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=35339" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/Feather_Falls_Mini_Mart_Gas_Stations/Oroville/35339/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">Feather Falls Mini Mart</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>6032 Lower Wyandotte Rd &amp; Pano Ln</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=35339&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Oroville/index.aspx" class="p_area">Oroville</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=Buddy_teu7p52u" class="mem">Buddy_teu7p52u</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_browncar"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 1:22 PM"> 4 hours ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_8" sm="8" ph="207925">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=207925" title="Update this price" class="p_price" id="p_207925"><div class="price_num" style="margin-left:12px">3.99</div></a><div style="margin-left:12px"><a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=207925" class="p_update">update</a></div>            
                    </th>
                    <td class="lf" style="width: 205px;">
                        <dl class="address">
                            <dt>             
                                <a href="/Costco_Gas_Stations/Redding/207925/index.aspx" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Station Details',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');">Costco</a>
                                
                            </dt>
                            <dd>4805 Bechelli LN near S Bonnyview Rd</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fts">                            
                            
                    <div style="margin: 2px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="/redirect.aspx?mapit_id=207925&amp;ft=A" class="p_flag p_map" onclick="ll('tagEvent', 'Opened Map',{'Context':'Stations List'});ll('setCustomerId', '');" title="Click here to view the station on the map">
                                            
                        </a>
                    </div>
                               
                           
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <a href="./Redding/index.aspx" class="p_area">Redding</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><div><a href="/Profile.aspx?member=uswhodo" class="mem">uswhodo</a><a href="/member_info.aspx"><div class="ci_cont ci_purplecar"></div></a></div></div><div class="tm" title="Tue 12:31 PM"> 5 hours ago</div>                                                         
                    </td> 
                </tr>
               
        
             
                <tr id="rrlow_9" sm="9" ph="14050">
                    <th class="p_low">       
                        <a href="/update_form.aspx?pid=14050" title="Update this price" 


the problem is you're appending twice per row. which returns obviously two lists per row. and you add the empty map field too
['3.85update'], ['Valero122 W Hermosa St & N Elmwood Ave', '', 'Lindsay', 'DAVEFMCC3 hours ago']
you need to append just once and filter out the empty values. i've changed the select too because you already parsed the headers
for row in table.select("tbody tr:has(th)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("th")]
    tdx = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td") if td.get_text(strip=True)]
    all_data.append(tds+tdx)

which returns
['3.85update', 'Valero122 W Hermosa St & N Elmwood Ave', 'Lindsay', 'DAVEFMCC3 hours ago']
now if you want to get rid of the junk text, you have no choice but to search for each field individually
for row in table.select("tbody tr:has(th)"):
    price = row.select_one("th .price_num").text
    address = row.select_one("td dl.address")
    station = (address.dt.text.strip(), address.dd.text)
    area = row.select_one("td a.p_area").text
    thanks = row.select_one("td a.mem").text

    all_data.append([price, station, area, thanks])

which returns
['3.85', ('Valero', '122 W Hermosa St & N Elmwood Ave'), 'Lindsay', 'DAVEFMCC']
note that station is a tuple (name, address)

Thanks, this works fantastic for me. I also went ahead and added more codes and modified a little bit for other type of gas as well. I will import the CSV tables to SQL database, and see if I can do some data cleaning for the Station column, which is a tuple.
